# How to display svg title content like an list rather than in straight line

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, hover, legend

I am creating discrete legend using SVG, where I am appending title to the rect to show content on hover but the content of title is displayed in straight line, which I want to come one after the other like list. Ex: Content 1 first and next line Content 2 and so on.

Part of Code Snippet:

// Have a div for which I am appending the svg

```
<div id="legend" ref={divRef}></div>
const currentDiv = select(divRef.current);

// creating svg
currentDiv
.append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${count} 1`)
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")

g.selectAll("g.legendCells")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g")
.append("rect")
.append("title")
.append("span")
.text(legendValues) // this is title content (array items)
```

[image]

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/r4Lafyjs/

Basically the title is array values like in format :

```
0: "Content_0"
1: "Content_1"
2: "Content_2"
3: "Content_3"
```

Which must be shown on hover over the rect cells, index: content

Comment: convert the commas to newlines.

Comment: Can you add the SVG code to your question? The markup that is the result of the code that you already showed.

Comment: I have added fiddle link above for more clarification

Comment: Most likely you rather need something like `.text(legendValues[i])`. Please add more details about your script (seems to use d3?)

Comment: Yes I am using D3 as well as I have my own color table set